# Webcomic about a group of professional monster killers

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

This one has been tickling the edge of my brain for a while. It was an anime-esque webcomic which I probably read in the early 2000 timeframe. The primary characters hunted down monsters and killed them as sort of an exterminator setup. I want to say that there were three of them with a female as their leader. The leader had been attacked by a monster before, leaving scars (on her chest?) which might have also been related to a dead younger sibling.

At the beginning, I remember them going on-scene to fight a monster and being confronted by the male representative of a government agency that was ostensibly devoted to ensuring that monsters were dealt with in a humane manner, but it was commonly known that they were trying to prevent the killing of any monsters at all. I think it was shortly thereafter revealed that either that official, or the protagonist, were monsters themselves who had found ways to rein in their bloodlust, proving that monsters didn't have to be shot on sight.

Given my usual propensities back in the day, this was probably a Keenspace comic, but I don't remember it being on Keenspot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be [Paranormal Mystery Squad](http://www.vampirecheerleaders.net/archive/paranormalmysterysquad1), it fits mostly what your described. A female lead, a team of three, monsters hunting, government agency against monster killing, and the anime style. Only downside is that it started in 2011.

This webcomic had its own website back in the day, but it's now merged with another.

Comment: I would swear I read it a good decade ago... but yeah, it otherwise matches.

Comment: And confirmation that indeed, it started in 2011. I guess it's my memories that are out of whack, because everything else fits.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly [*Skin Horse*](http://skin-horse.com/cast/) , which first "aired" in 2007 (the comic is mildly NSFW). By Shaenon K. Garrity (creator of [*Narbonic*](http://www.narbonic.com/) ; *Skin Horse* is set in the *Narbonic* universe) and Jeffrey Channing Wells.

[image]

Comment: No. That came later. And I am familiar with Skin Horse. This one looked like an actual anime style. And the protagonists were out to kill the monsters, not to provide government support. :)